# Shuffle an Array in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, shuffle

I want to shuffle an array in java but not to change the original list, only shuffle the temporary list.

I wrote something like this.

```
    ArrayList<TristateCheckBox> tempList = buttons; 
Collections.shuffle(tempList);
```

But this not shuffles only tempList also changes the buttons list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to take a copy of the List, not just a copy of the reference to the list.

```
List<TristateCheckBox> tempList = new ArrayList<TristateCheckBox>(buttons); 
Collections.shuffle(tempList);
```

Answer (score 2):

tempList is a pointer to the buttons object.  tempList and buttons point to the same location in memory.  You have to actually copy the data to maintain the order in the original list.  Look into Arrays: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html for a method that copies the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply assigning the same `buttons` ArrayList instance to another variable. `tempList` is gonna end up referring to the same ArrayList.

Try this instead:

```
List<TristateCheckBox> tempList = new ArrayList<TristateCheckBox>(buttons);
Collections.shuffle(tempList);
```

That ArrayList constructor taking another Collection will include every entry of the given Collection in the new list. Not copies of the entries, just the same references in a different list.